# Save as csv file of datawindow ,taking a lot of time

Tags: powerbuilder

I save a csv file of datawindow(powerbuilder) ,that contains a lot of computes (300) , and system needs 40 minutes to save this file .What the problem may be? 
I have deleted fields from sybase.

Thanks

Comment: “Deleted fields from Sybase” suggests to me this isn’t the system function dw.SaveAs(), but something custom built in Powerscript. Is that correct? When you say “computes”, do you mean DW/client-side computes, or DBMS/server-side computes?

Comment: Hello Terry , 'deleted Files froma sybase' , i mean that, manually i deleted fields to check  speed differences. Also, 'computes' means DW/client-side computes. I dont know if i make hardware changes to pc, if there is any significant difference.

Comment: I’m still not clear. Foremost importance is whether this is dw.SaveAs() or custom script; the difference will take answers in completely different directions. (I’m not picturing DW computes included in dw.SaveAs(CSV), which is part of why I’m asking.) If you deleted all your columns from the database and the compute expressions still worked, I’m guessing the computes aren’t against the columns. What do they do? First guess would be global functions, which are notoriously slow.

Comment: SaveAs dont save values of data Window and i use SaveAsAscii that save all values of data Window in CSV file. All computes run before saving.

Comment: The computes may run before savings, but that doesn’t mean the may not *run again*. Since expression can contain things like “am I on the currently visible page” or “if this column has focus...”, there are many triggers for recalculating. You should probably run a trace (either PBDEBUG or profiler should work, I think) to confirm or deny whether or not your expressions are recomputing, and possibly how many times. Which leads us back to the question: what are your computes doing? If they are compute-intensive, that may be the explanation as to why.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me with pbdebug and profiler, i found computes that takes a lot of time and i simplified these. Now time is 50% less!!!